# SQL Server table changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

So I've noticed over the past few weeks that changing tables in SQL Server is very difficult, such as specifying a new primary key column or changing a column definition (ie. changing it's datatype).  Half of the time I have to drop the table and start over.  Or even re-ordering columns in a table results in about a half hour of working (even though it doesn't really matter to the databse engine what order they are in, but I like to have things in logical order).

Are there any simpler ways to make changes to tables like this without having to go through headaches of dropping tables or recreating them.  Most of the time I get an error saying that the table has to be dropped and recreated but apparently SQL server can't do this.  I don't want to turn off the "Prevent table changes from requiring a table to be dropped" option because of the possiblye problems it can cause later.

Sometimes, for example, I can cheat and generate a CREATE TABLE script and then change the definition of a table in the script, drop the actual table, and create it again with the script ,but sometimes this doesn't work.  And re-ordering columns is a pain and a problem, or even changing data types in a column that's already in the table, or setting a primary key, or changing a field from "NULL" to "NOT NULL" using the checkbox.
Any ideas on how to better manage the tables and make changes?  It frustrates me that Microsoft did not follow the SQL standard on some of its ALTER TABLE commands, among other things.  In MYSQL this would be a lot easier, but we are using SQL Server unfortunately.

Comment: For example, I had a column that I had to change from a TINYINT to a SMALLINT and for some reason, I got the error stating that the table has to be dropped and recreated but SQL server couldn't do it.  A simple change like this using ALTER COLUMN should work (and it works as it should in MySQL) but in SQL SERVER for some reason, this becomes a big chore at times.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to make a comment directly in response to your own question (or answers). If you have more to add, please **edit** your question to add extra text (or to correct any problems, etc)